# Add OSM baselayer within WMS layers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

how can I add OSM be the base layer? Below is what I have and the part within asterisk is where I want to place an OSM.

```
var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
region: "center",
center: [27.795971, -25.609990],
zoom: 11,
layers: [ * * new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {
            layers: 'basic'
        }, * * {
            buffer: 0,
            // exclude this layer from layer container nodes
            displayInLayerSwitcher: false
        }),
    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Madibeng City",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
            layers: "topp:Madibeng0",
            transparent: true,
            format: "image/gif"
        }, {
            buffer: 0
        }),
    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Madibeng Road Network",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
            layers: "Madibeng_LM_RoadNetwork0",
            transparent: true,
            format: "image/gif"
        }, {
            buffer: 0
        }),
    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Madibeng Paved Locations",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
            layers: "topp:Verf_Paved0",
            transparent: true,
            format: "image/gif"
        }, {
            buffer: 0
        })
 ]
 });
```

Comment: Just use `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM`, per http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/OSM-js.html

Comment: or use http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org which replaces http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0

Comment: BaseLayer which is the full map is not displayed and the zoom function is disturbed. The zoom is functioning but deformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine a OpenLayers.Layer.OSM-Baselayer with OpenLayers.Layer.WMS-Overlays in GeoExt you should either use displayOutsideMaxExtent for your WMS-Layers or define a MaxExtent for your map:

```
// define the MaxExtent for the map

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(1247348.5486233, -4263307.2348958,
                                        4260801.9513187, -2448386.4355452)
                         });

// create OSM Layer

    var osm_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

// create MapPanel with center-point in epsg 3857!

     var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
            title: "Map",
            region: "center",
            height: 400,
            width: 300,
            map: map,
            center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(24.740278910086, -28.844323887404).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()),
            zoom: 5
        });

    // create wms layer

    var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "WMS Layer South Africa",
            "http://gis.lib.virginia.edu:8080/geoserver/South_Africa/wms", {
            layers: 'South_Africa:popoint_point',
            transparent: true
        }, {
            isBaseLayer: false
            //, displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
        });



// add Layers

map.addLayers([osm_layer, wmsLayer]);
```

Here you will find a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/hgrnhofc/